# In Android, how to architect in-app purchases using google account to idenify users?

Tags: android, billing

I'm writing an application which (for now) has no backend. It operates only with local data.

The application will have 2 versions:

- Free: some features will be limited and there will be an ad banner
- Paid: a single payment will unblock the app and eliminate the banner

As I understand it, I need to identify a user in some way in order to determine he/she made the payment.

I'd also like to allow users to identify themselves without a registration process. I thought of the Google one-tap sign-in feature. However, I do notice that this feature implies logging in against Google's backend server, which in the case of this strictly off-line app seems overkill.

What's a good solution for this use-case?
How to implement a univocal but seamless identification of users using Google account e-mails, without involving Google's servers?

Comment: google can provide a billing token showing that they purchased the full version.  See this site for more info.  https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing